# Why is following query taking forever to show results?

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT     ba.bug_id, 
               ba.bug_when, 
               b.short_desc 
    FROM       bugs_activity ba 
    INNER JOIN bugs b 
    order BY   bug_id DESC 
    LIMIT      10
```

The above query should return data from 2 tables (bugs_activity & bugs). But it just going into an infinite loop. What could be wrong?

Using EXPLAIN before the query returned the following result -

[image]

Comment: You have no `ON` clause for the `JOIN` ,so you're getting a cartesian product it looks like. That could be a very large rowset.

Comment: But, MySQL doesn't loop in a select statement. So if you think there's an infinite loop going on, that's in your application code somewhere and not this query  (despite the join being incorrect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it happens because there is no information in query for what fields make this relation, so the resultset is too big and perform a timeout.

You need inform on your join clause what field in BUGS is related with BUGS_ACTIVITY.

For example, if you have two tables, Customer and Customer_Contact, in your table Customer_Contact you have a field that is a foreign key to table Customer. You need provide this information in your query:

```
SELECT cus.*
  FROM customer cus
 INNER JOIN customer_contact con ON con.customer_id = cus.id
```

That is just an example, if you provide what fields exists in both tables it could helps. I can imagine something like that:

```
SELECT     ba.bug_id, 
           ba.bug_when, 
           b.short_desc 
FROM       bugs_activity ba 
INNER JOIN bugs b ON ba.bug_id = b.id
order BY   bug_id DESC 
LIMIT      10
```